# Tag synonym request: [hotkeys] and [keyboard-shortcuts]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are 18 questions tagged [hotkeys](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotkeys) and 14 questions tagged [keyboard-shortcuts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) (and of these, [3 questions share both tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts+hotkeys)). I can't quite see the difference, I really think one of these tags should be made a synonym of the other.

As for which should be the primary tag, I think both are fine; I suppose [hotkeys](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotkeys) has proven to have *slightly* more questions so it might as well be chosen.

Comment: Funny thing, I just [suggested](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/keyboard-shortcuts/synonyms) that. Would've done so sooner, but apparently tag score takes ages to update.

Answer (score 1):

Nicely spotted. This has been done.